# how to pass file from client to controller by jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to create very simple sample to uploading a file by client side in mvc4 by jquery and java script.

i Google it and found many samples and many plugins on internet but i prefer to do not have any dependency on any extra plugin or library like "uploadify"

for this i create a simple mvc4 application and in my view i attach my script file that contains method bellow until user click a button on this view start to uploading.

i do not know how to change bellow method to pass file to controller(in client side) ?

```
function uploadimage() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Uploader/FileUpload",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:null,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: function (xhr) {

    }
});
```

}

in my view

```
   <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />
   <input type="button"  value ="Upload"  onclick="uploadimage()"/>
```

my controller

```
 public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
       //do somethings with file
     }
```

Comment: You'll need to use a plugin if you want to do it via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

file upload is not possible through ajax. You can upload file, without refreshing page by using IFrame.